# Check if container has Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, styling

I have a form. The structure looks like this:

```
<p class="elementWrap">
  <label>Name</label>
  <input class="form_elem" type="text" name="form_name">
</p>
```

But sometimes the structure looks like this:

```
<p class="elementWrap">
  <label>Phone</label>
  <input class="form_elem" type="text" name="form_phone">
  <span class="form_required">*</span>
</p>
```

So there is an additional span in it.
Now I want to give the labels, which have a span next to them some styles with jQuery.

My code so far:

```
jQuery('.elementWrap').each(function() {
  if(jQuery('span.form_required').parents(this).length == 1) {
    jQuery(this).find('label').css({'width':'auto','margin':'0px'});
  }
});
```

But this doesn't seem to work...(I tried a lot of if statements but none worked so far =/

Comment: There is always `Node.contains`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.contains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [.filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter) and [.children](http://api.jquery.com/children) to select all `.elementWrap` objects which have a direct `.form_required` child - then find the labels within that subset:

```
$(".elementWrap").filter(function() {
    return $(this).children(".form_required").length;
}).find("label").css({'width':'auto','margin':'0px'});
```

[<kbd>jsFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/uj43z/)

There is almost always a way to avoid having to use `.each` and a lot of `if` statements.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `:has()` pseudo selector, e.g:

```
$('.elementWrap:has(.form_required)').find('label').css({'width':'auto','margin':'0px'});
```

### DEMO

Comment: Although I get the idea, I think the OP wants to select the `label` where `.elementWrap:has(.form_required)`. i.e. `$('.elementWrap:has(.form_required)').find("label")`...

Comment: +1 Definitely easier to read than filter. For OP: `:has` searches all descendants rather than just direct children.

Answer (score 0):

do like this:

```
$('p.elementWrap').each(function(){

if($(this).find('span.form_required').length > 0)
{
    $(this).find('label').css('background','red');
    // do whatever needed
}

})
```

[**Here is Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/b8bpL/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('.elementWrap').each(function () {
    if ($(this).find('span.form_required').length != 0) {
        $(this).find('label').css({
            'width': 'auto',
            'margin': '0px'
        });
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pb2XR/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jQuery('.elementWrap').has('.form_required').find('label').css({'width':'auto','margin':'0px'});
```

I made a JSFiddle for you:
[Click for the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gNj3K/)

Explanation:
First i select every element with an elementWrap class (no need to do an each)
But I only select those, which HAS a child with a form_required class with the .has() method.
From those elementWrap elements i want to find the label and apply some custom style!

Hope this helped you out!